# How do I jQuery create a parameterized animation of an element moving along a sine wave pattern?

Tags: jquery, animation, path

I have a bunch (4) elements on a page that I want to fly in from right to left along a sine wave path. I want to be able to pass in the start and end point of the animations as parameters, or minimally, set the start point in the CSS and pass the end point as a parameter.

I found this jQuery path plugin: https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path

I'm sure I can do it with this, but I don't understand how to do it in the parameterized way I'm aiming for, based on example given for the sine wave path in the docs/demo. So I'm looking for some help understanding the example or an explanation of how to do this.

Also I am aware of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802243/jquery-animating-along-a-sine-wave), but it doesn't answer my question.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elem_1").animate({
    path : new $.path.bezier({
        start: { 
            x: 185, //here is where you put your start X coordinate
            y: 185, //here is where you put your start Y coordinate
            angle: 10
        },  
        end: { 
            x:540,//end X coordinate
            y:110, //end Y coordinate
            angle: -10, 
            length: 0.25
        }
      })
  });
```

You can just do this for all four of your elements. If you want the animations to start at different times you can use `setTimeout` to stagger their starting times, or if you want one at a time to animate you can use the callback function of the `.animate()` function to run one after another.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to move along a sinusoidal path - are you suggesting using multiple linked bezier curves to achieve this?

Comment: @paul Ah I see, well you *could* use the callback function of the `.animate()` function to do that.

Comment: Right, that works. Is the sine wave demo in the documentation not meant to do this? Because I don't really see a way to do it with that.